# How does Tomcat7 security sample calls login.jsp?

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, tomcat7, sample

If I open a sample URL http://localhost:8080/examples/jsp/security/protected/index.jsp first time, I will see login form with `username` and `password` fields. Html code of this form is located in `login.jsp` file, but I see no code to call it from `index.jsp`. How does this call fullfilled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined in the corresponding `web.xml`:

```
<!-- Default login configuration uses form-based authentication -->
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/jsp/security/protected/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/jsp/security/protected/error.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

You find the file in `<tomcat>/webapps/examples/WEB-INF`. It utilizes the built-in Java EE security features. The preceeding `security-constraint` section defines the resources to be protected:

```
   <security-constraint>
      <display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
         <!-- Define the context-relative URL(s) to be protected -->
         <url-pattern>/jsp/security/protected/*</url-pattern>
         <!-- If you list http methods, only those methods are protected -->
         <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
         <http-method>GET</http-method>
         <http-method>POST</http-method>
         <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
         <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
         <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
         <role-name>role1</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```